# How can I open and close div tag inside a foreach loop of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Below is my sample array.

```
$myArray = [
   'A', 
   'B', 
   'new-div', 
   'C', 
   'D', 
   'E', 
   'new-div', 
   'F', 
   'new-div', 
   'G', 
   'H', 
   'I', 
   'J', 
   'new-div', 
   'K',
];
```

Below is my foreach loop.

```
foreach($myArray as $item) {
    echo '<div>' . $item . '</div>';
}
```

You might know what the result is from the foreach loop above. But this is not what I want. How can I get the result as follows?

```
<div>
   <div>A</div>
   <div>B</div>
</div>
<div class='new-div'>
   <div>C</div>
   <div>D</div>
   <div>E</div>
</div>
<div class='new-div'>
   <div>F</div>
</div>
<div class='new-div'>
   <div>G</div>
   <div>H</div>
   <div>I</div>
   <div>J</div>
</div>
<div class='new-div'>
   <div>K</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the desired result please. That might help us

Comment: I would rebuild your array to be a multidimensional, and if an array resides inside an array, i will create the div wrapping. Are you allowed to change the array to a multidimensional array?

Comment: @ RiggsFolly, Sorry I just edited my question

Comment: @CodeGodie: Yes I may change the original array into a dimensional array but I don't how to do that with a if-statement inside the foreach loop. I am still trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as CodeGodie suggested, if you are able to make an other array, it is even better :

```
$myArray = array(
    array(
        "NoClass" => array(
                             'A', 
                             'B')),
     array(
        "new-div" => array(
                             'C', 
                             'D', 
                             'E')),
     array(
        "new-div" => array(
                             'F')),
     array(
        "new-div" => array(
                             'G', 
                             'H', 
                             'I', 
                             'J')),
     array(
        "new-div" => array(
                             'K'));
    );
```

and then use this code :

```
foreach($myArray as $parentDiv) {
    foreach($parentDiv as $className => $subDivs) {
        if($className === "NoClass") {
            $divClass = "";
        else {
            $divClass =  " class='".$className."'";
        }

        // make a new parent div
        echo "<div".$divClass.">";
        // echo subdivs
        foreach($subDivs as $subDiv) {
            echo '<div>' . $subDiv . '</div>';
        }
        // end of parent div
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I make it into a dimensional array as your sample above?

Comment: @OConnor are you building this array yourself or is it dynamically being built?

Comment: If you receive the array, as in your question, from elsewhere (webservice...), it is not usefull to change it into the one we suggest. But if you make it yourself, it depends how you make it.

Comment: @CodeGodie it is a dynamically being built. I want to change my desired result a little bit more since I also want a parent div around the first items. Please help me.

Comment: Sure.. you would need to provide us with more information on how it is dynamically built though. Currently, how is the array being constructed? can you provide that code?

Comment: the array is built based on the database records, which means each item is one record. When I select all records from a database table I get it as an array as you could see in my sample array above.

Comment: @OConnor could you edit your question with the loop building it from DataBase ? You mean in database, you have all those 15 lines ? (sounds strange-built database...)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$divOpen = false;
foreach($myArray as $item) {
    if($item == 'new-div'){
        if($divOpen == true){ echo '</div>'; }
        echo '<div class="new-div">';
        $divOpen = true;
    }else {
        echo '<div>' . $item . '</div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rebuild your array to be a multidimensional array like this:

```
$myArray = [
    'A',
    'B',
    array('C', 'D', 'E'),
    array('F'),
    array('G', 'H', 'I', 'J'),
    array('K')
];
```

Then iterate this way:

```
foreach ($myArray as $item) {
    if (is_array($item)) {
        $html = '<div class="new-div">';
        foreach ($item as $letter) {
            $html .= "<div>$letter</div>";
        }
        $html .= '</div>';
    } else {
        $html = "<div>$item</div>";
    }
    echo $html;
}
```

Comment: Thats intentional because for every iteration `$html` is already defined either at the `if` or `else` block,. and `$html` does not need to be initialized.

Comment: i think you are right about it resetting. I will double check... but `$html` does not need to be init

Comment: i double checked. It works fine. and yea I am sure about not initializing it. In this case you don't, because it initializes it self every time per iteration.

Comment: Yeah, I thought you were filling `$html` with the whole output, instead of just one loop step, so you would have to use `.=` everywhere... here it's fine, I delete comments :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it, inspired by Random and CodeGodie.

```
        $divEnding = '';
        $initDiv = true;
        $firstNewDiv = 0;

        foreach($myArray as $item) {
            if($initDiv) {
                echo "<div class='no-class'>"; 
            }

            if($item === 'new-div') {
                $firstNewDiv++;
                if($firstNewDiv == 1) {
                    echo '</div>';
                }

                echo $divEnding;
                echo "<div class='new-div'>";
                $divEnding = "</div>";
            } else {
                echo '<div>' . $item . '</div>';
            }

            $initDiv = false;
        }

        if($divEnding !== "") {
            echo $divEnding;
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

I would use a $count variable - increment it at the of every iteration of the foreach

```
    $count = 0;

    foreach($myArray as $item) {
         if($count == X || $count == Y){
         echo '<div class='new-div'>'.
         '<div>' . $item . '</div>';
    }
    else if($count == Z || $count == A){
    echo '<div>' . $item . '</div>'.'</div>';
    }
else{
echo '<div>' . $item . '</div>';
    }
$count++;
}
```

Comment: many coding problems here... `$count` is an integer, and you compare it with unquoted chars... And where does X, Y, Z, A come from ?

Comment: I agree with @Random , `$count` will never be X, Y.. Also, these are strings so they really should be `"X", "Y"` surrounded in quotes, regardless, it still is wrong.